# app.use() requires middleware functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using express and node js for my app

my main index.js file is

```
var express = require("express");
var app = module.exports = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , assert = require('assert');

var myProject= require("services");

app.use(myProject.callService());
```

and my services.js file is

```
var res = module.exports;

res.callService = function () {
    console.log('here ===')
}
```

but when I am trying to call this callService function from index.js I am getting an error

app.use() requires middleware functions

can you please tell what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `undefined` (which is what `myProject.callService()` returns) isn't valid middleware.

Comment: so how can I make it as a valid middleware,
I have tried it as 

exports.callService= function () {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        next();
    }
}

but not working

Comment: By passing the function instead of executing it.

Comment: hey kevin what is this site for, I think asking questions about which one have confusion. So instead of giving answers why are you keep on marking it negative. and I don't think it is an irrelevent question

Comment: I didn't mark it as negative. I can comment and leave feedback without voting.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but your question doesn't show that you've read or studied any of the simple examples of middleware as any middleware must either call `next()` or finish the request itself so even if you had passed the middleware function reference correctly, what you have still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a middleware function, not pass the result of calling your endpoint handler.

services.js

```
// a middleware function gets the request(`req`), response(`res`)
// and a `next` function to pass control to the next handler
// in the pipeline.
exports.callService = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('here ===');
    res.status(200).end();
};
```

index.js

```
/* setup stuff... */
// notice here we do not call callService, but pass it
// to be called by the express pipeline.
app.use(myProject.callService);
```